# how do i combine scenes with video footage in Blender VSE?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, masking

So, I have a video project I am working on, and decided to move away from Hitfilm Express and give Blender a shot. So, what i used to do in Hitfilm, is i will make a composite shot and then bring it into the sequence editor, and then add the video footage into the sequencer. 
When i use Blender, I assume that the "composite shot" is indeed the scenes, and  I bring in the scenes into the VSE just like how I do it in Hitfilm.

So, I created an intro with text and a mask object (will provide a link to the .blend file). I added a scene strip into the VSE, and rendered it from the VSE. I then realized it was rendering the masking objects (plane) too. I then switched the Scene Preview/Render to Rendered, and then rendered it. This time the masking objects did not show. I was very happy.

But then, when I rendered it the second time (from the VSE), there was a bug:
[image: this is the bug]

I then spent the next 2 days or so searching in many forums, searching in documentation, searching everywhere, but I could not fix this bug.

Anyone have any ideas?

here is the .blend file.

[image]

Comment: I fail to replicate any issues with the file provided. Everything works as it should. It renders fine as it is or as a strip in VSE. Could you tell more about what problems exactly you are experiencing and what you do with the file before experiencing them?

Comment: @MartinZ I did nothing to the file before bringing the scene strip into the VSE and rendering from the VSE. Did you render with F12 or in the VSE?

Comment: It is animation, so I rendered it as animation. To render from VSE I added the scene as a strip and disabled Compositing in render settings under Post Processing. It works fine this way, as well as just opening the file and hitting Animation under Render.

Comment: @MartinZ ok, I will try doing that

Comment: You said 'I added a scene strip into the VSE, and rendered it from the VSE.'. How else did you do that? If you just add the strip and hit render, it will render the scene, not the Sequencer, however that works fine as well. I am confused.

Comment: Okie, but. When you rendered, did the two masking planes show? And I meant I will try disabling compositing in the post.processing properties

Comment: Everything in the file works as it is supposed to. If you need further help, please edit the question and clarify what the issue is.